# ElasticSearch types coerce from long to double

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ES version 2.2.0

I have a field which may have long or double values.
How can I make ElasticSearch coerce long values to double so that I don't get conflicts when inserting new documents?

For example, if the value is 5 I'd like ES to coerce it into 5.0 so that I can insert 12.3 afterwards.

Is there some kind of dynamic index template I can apply to make that conversion automatic upon insertion?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply set the type of that field to `double` in the mapping and that does the job. Anything you'll feed into that field will get coerced into a double.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index -d '{
  "mappings": {       
     "type": {
        "properties": {
            "myfield": {
                "type": "double"
            }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

You need to do that at index/mapping creation time, otherwise you cannot change the type after the mapping has been created.

**UPDATE**

You can also leverage [dynamic mapping templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "doubles": {
            "match_mapping_type": "long",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to be more agile than this regarding fields. What would be the way to do this via dynamic index templates?